# $f(n) =$ the smallest prime factor of $n$. Prove that the number of solutions to the equation $f(x) = 2016$.

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f$ be a continuous function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ (where $\mathbb R$ is the set of all real numbers) that
satisfies the following property: For every natural number $n$

$f(n) =$ the smallest prime factor of $n$.
For example, $f(12) = 2$, $f(105) = 3$. Calculate the following.

(a) $\lim_\limits{x→∞} f(x)$.

(b) The number of solutions to the equation $f(x) = 2016$.

Is the following reasoning correct for the a part?
' As there are infinite primes, if we assume that ∞ is a prime number, then $f(x)$= $∞$, thus $\lim_{x→∞}$ does not exist.'

In the b part the answer can be obtained by using intermediate value theorem, but shouldn't $f(x)$ not be equal to $2016$ as it is a composite number?

Here's the link to the original question [Question Paper](http://www.cmi.ac.in/admissions/sample-qp/ugmath2017-solutions.pdf)

Part A - 9th question.

Comment: $2016$ is not a prime, so...

Comment: For (a) compute $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(2^n)$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(3^n)$.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2755961/solutions-to-a-fx-2016).  That one was closed because it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @lulu Yes for part (b), but the linked question doesn't contain part (a).

Comment: @lulu This question came in the entrance of CMI, it's the most prestigious math institute in India. So I highly doubt that b part of this question is wrong.

Comment: The question is nonsense, sorry.

Comment: @lulu I agree, but I have to cross check with others to see if there is really a solution.

Comment: It's not nonsense, just not a very interesting question : as $2016$ is not prime, there is no solutions to this equation, so the answer is $0$.

Comment: @Tryss  Not necessarily.  The function is defined, supposedly, from $\mathbb R$ to itself.  It could hit $2016$ any number of times between any two specified natural numbers, for example.

Comment: @Tryss They have given a solution, it's this  'By intermediate value theorem, for each prime p > 2016 there is an x
between p and p + 1 such that f(x) = 2016.'

Comment: @Raghav  Perhaps critical information has been omitted.  Can you reprint the question exactly as it appears?  Even if not in English, someone here will be able to read it.  Or provide a link to the source.

Comment: @lulu Here's the [link](http://www.cmi.ac.in/admissions/sample-qp/ugmath2017-solutions.pdf)   Part A - Question 9.

Comment: Ok, got it.  It's trivial:   All they want you to say is that there are infinitely many such $x$.  The proof is easy:  Let $p_i$ be any prime greater than $2016$.  Then there is a solution to $f(x)=2016$ between $p_i-1$ and $p_i$ since $f(p_i-1)=2$ and $f(p_i)=p_i>2016$.

Comment: I'll post something below.  Edit:  actually, the posted solution from @HagenvonEitzen  says everything I was going to write, so I won't post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) Your argument is not ok. $\infty$ is not a prime. However, there are arbitrarily large $x$ where $f(x)=2$ and arbitrarily large $x$ where $f(x)=3$ (think of $x=2^n$ and $x=3^n$, for example). Hence $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ cannot exist.

(b) Between $x_n=2017^n$ where $f(x_n)=2017$ and the even number $x_n+1$ where $f(x_n+1)=2$, the continuity of $f$ guarantees the existence of at least one point $y_n$ where $f(y_n)=2016$. Hence there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Can you please explain (a) in more detail? And is this reasoning correct? Let $n$ be a prime number, then $f(n)$ = $n$. $\lim_\limits{n→∞}$  $f(n)$ = $∞$.Thus the limit does not exist.